# Winform distances from edges

Tags: winforms

Which property of visual control permits to maintain a constant distances from the edges of a parent form or container control when the parent is resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `Margin` property, `Margin="0,10,0,25"` (left, top, right, bottom).